# Link tracking with nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I want to create a service to track affiliate link clicks. The logic is simple, When a user is clicked on the link provided by the service will redirect to an original affiliate link.

I stored data in MongoDB. I want to get the original affiliate link bypassing the offerID(Service provided offerID).

I wrote the following code:

```
app.get('/click', async (req, res) => {

    //Tracking link : https://myservice.com/click?a=500&o=15112

    const url =req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + req.originalUrl
    const affiliateId = new URL(url).searchParams.get('a')
    const offerID = new URL(url).searchParams.get('o')
    //Getting affiliateID and offerID from URL

    const link = await Links.findOne({oID: offerID}) //Getting the affiliate link from the MongoDB by passing offerID
    if (link == null) return res.sendStatus(404)

    const userAgent =  navigator.userAgent //Getting the userAgent
    const clickID = shortId.generate //Generating a unique clickID
    const finalLink = link.affiliateLink.concat(`&clickID=${clickID}&sub1=${affiliateId}`) //Creating the link from the affiliates
    //Link will be like https://offer.com/clicks?affiliateoffer=500&affiliateid=1000&clickID=12151212121&sub1=500

    const click = new Click({
        affID: affiliateId,
        oID: offerID,
        clickID: clickID,
        userAgent: userAgent,
    });

    Click.save(click) // Saving the click on the database(mongodb)
    res.redirect(finalLink) //Redirecting to affiliate link
})
```

Will that work when thousands of clicks at the same time?
Any improvements that I can do to increase the redirection time?

Comment: Regardless of performance, you will need to `await` the `save` call since it returns a `Promise` and call it on the document instance: `await click.save()`